# Passing in parameter for a select alias

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

In a Pl sql function in need to pass in varchar parameter for a select statement alias. For example something like below,

```
create or replace
FUNCTION XX_FUNC_TEST (p_id in varchar2 , p_app_type in varchar2) RETURN varchar2 IS

appl_type_r varchar2(20);

BEGIN
  SELECT p_app_type 
  INTO appl_type_r
  FROM YY_TABLE
  WHERE trans_id = p_id;

  dbms_output.put_line(appl_type_r);

  RETURN appl_type_r;

END XX_FUNC_TEST;
```

So its like the real column name is applicant_type which i pass as a parameter. But some how the out put i get is applicant_type which i pass as the parameter not the column value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to create your query dynamically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XX_FUNC_TEST (p_id in varchar2 , p_app_type in varchar2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    appl_type_r VARCHAR2(20);
    sql VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
    sql := 
        'SELECT ' || p_app_type || ' ' ||
        'FROM YY_TABLE ' ||
        'WHERE trans_id = p_id';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql INTO appl_type_r;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(appl_type_r);

    RETURN appl_type_r;
END XX_FUNC_TEST;
```

Otherwise, Oracle thinks you just want to select the value itself.